# How can you debug Classic ASP on an Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, vbscript, asp-classic, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and a Classic ASP app running on an Azure Web App.

In VS, on the Server Explorer, I can right-click on the Azure Web App and select Attach Debugger.

PROBLEM: it attaches to debug "Managed Code" which isn't helpful since VBScript isn't managed code.  I can set breakpoints in the default.asp file (for example) which show up as filled red dots suggesting it's loaded symbols, which is encouraging, but the breakpoint is never hit.

QUESTION: how can I get it to connect and debug "Script"?

FYI I can do this just fine against iisexpress.exe running on my local dev machine.  I see "Script, Managed Code" as available options, and can select "Script".  The exact same breakpoint gets hit as I'd expect.

Has anyone gotten this working successfully against an Azure Web App?  If so, how did you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using manual attach (see [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/))? This should let you choose what to debug. Though I've never tried Classic...

Comment: @DavidEbbo Yes, thanks, I have. My point is that in the Type column on the list of processes you can attach to, w3svc shows only "Managed" and not "Script" so I can't usefully attach and debug VBscript.  How can I get it to show "Script" as an option?!?

Comment: It doesn't show script even after making a classic request? Not sure why